# How does one properly indicate a translator's explanation of a word within a translated passage

Tags: formatting

I have a paper with one or two multi-sentence translations from classical Chinese.  How do I explain certain things in the text that are assumed by the author but would not be known by modern readers? I have seen where a translator presents within his translation comments or explanations; however, I don't know the proper way to format and mark these.  Is it (xxxxxx xx xxxx x, tr.)?

Comment: @earthling, promote your comment to an answer.  I'd vote it up.

Answer (score 3):

Any time you need to give additional information for readers, and you do not want to interrupt the flow of reading, [footnotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footnotes) are generally considered the best way.

This is common for translation notes or any other information which the reader might need for a fuller understanding of your text.